# Can't unwrap Optional.None

Tags: swift

I try to access a property:

```
let ejh = userInfo.firstName;
```

But I get this error:

```
fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
```

Why?

userInfo has a type `CKDiscoveredUserInfo!`

Comment: probably .firstName or userInfo itself is an optional variable (defined with ? question mark), and it's None (undefined). Check this article https://medium.com/arthurs-coding-tips/optionals-in-swift-c94fd231e7a4 and this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006287/cant-unwrap-optional-none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line should be `let ejh = userInfo.firstName?` because firstName could have nil value

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers to this e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006287/cant-unwrap-optional-none?rq=1).

`userInfo` (which you don't show the definition of) is presumably an optional value (i.e. could be `nil`). Use this instead:

```
if let ejh = userInfo.firstName {
    println("Got it!\(ejh)")
} else {
    println("nil")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the value of userInfo.firstName is optional, can be nil.
You need to unwrap it.
If you are sure that there is a value you can use force unwrap:

```
let ejh = userInfo.firstName!
```

But if you are not sure there is a value use:

```
if let ejh = userInfo.firstName {
    // use ejh here
}
```

Another way to get the value is:

```
let ejh = userInfo?.firstName;
```

This gives you value if userInfo has one or it gives you nil instead.

Comment: if let ejh = userInfo.firstName { <- cause the same crash

Comment: Probably its because userInfo is optional, not just first name. The last option should work for you.